# Cat fang poking hole in lip

Tags: cats, diseases, dental-care

I have a 1.5 year old Maine Coon cat.

One of the cat's upper fangs appears to be poking a hole in its lower lip. Only the right side lip has a hole in it; the left side has a small bump instead of a hole.

[image]

<sup>I pulled the lower lip away from the fang for the purpose of this photo. Normally, the fang sits right in the hole in the lip.</sup>

---

[image]

<sup>I pulled the cat's upper lip back for the purpose of this photo.</sup>

---

Question:

Is there a technical name for when a fang pokes a hole in a lip, and can it cause health problems for cats?

---

Edit 2021-09-14:

The hole in the lip eventually just went away.

Comment: are you sure your cat did not have an infection in the lip that was the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since it healed by itself, I would guess this is just the same as humans accidentally biting our tongues or cheeks -- shouldn't happen, theoretically, but it does. And landing badly after a jump might increase the risk.

Unless it happens more than once or twice a year, I don't think I would worry about it.